# Foreign Key not linking correctly

Tags: php, mysql

When registering my first user in table 'users' the id is the same value as user_id in the linking table,1, (language). However, when I register another user (id2 in users) the user_id in language is still 1. See SQL:

```
 CREATE TABLE `language` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `native` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `other` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `other_list` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 `other_read` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 `other_spokint` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 `other_spokprod` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
 `other_writ` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;


 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `md5_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` tinytext CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `user_level` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `pwd` varchar(220) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `department` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` date NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `users_ip` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `activation_code` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `banned` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `ckey` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ctime` varchar(220) NOT NULL,
  `approved` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

This is my PHP code:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['$user_id']))  { // user not logged in; redirect to somewhere else }
if (!empty($_POST['doLanguage']) && $_POST['doLanguage'] == 'Submit') 
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE `banned` = '0'") or 
die   (mysql_error());


list($id) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id']= $id;

sql_insert = "INSERT into `language`
(`user_id`,`native`,`other`,`other_list`,`other_read`, `other_spokint`
,`other_spokprod`,`other_writ`  )
VALUES
('$id','$native','$other','$other_list','$other_read','$other_spokint',
'$other_spokprod','$other_writ') ";

mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());     
}

header("Location: myaccount.php?id=' . $_SESSION[user_id] .'");
exit();
```

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Where is $id populated? Or is this line written backwards: "$_SESSION['user_id']= $id;"

Comment: @Yamikuronue - it comes from the `list` construct that works with the fetched resultset.

Comment: @Yamikuronue i tried to write it the other way but still had the problem of user_id 1 when it should be 2.thanks

Comment: I see no foreign keys in your tables. And the column "banned" is an integer; don't quote it.

Comment: foreign key is KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) in first table listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because your initial select query is selecting all users that are not banned

So need to change the query to filter by the new user:

```
"SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE `banned` = '0' and id=" . $_SESSION['$user_id'];
```

The reason why the user_id field kept getting populated as 1 was because mysql_fetch_row was getting the first record which was user id 1.

So if you filter it by the new user, mysql_fetch_row should get the id of the new user.

**EDIT**

I'm just looking at the code again, and it looks like you do not store the user id in php after you insert it, so your user_id for $_SESSION is null.

So my above example will not work. Instead of the above query, use the following function to get the id of your newly created user. You call this function after you run your insert query. That function will get the new of your newly created user.

`mysql_insert_id()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

**EDIT 2**

Ok, since mysql_insert_id() didn't work for you, maybe you can try the following. I just changed your select query to order by id desc.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE `banned` = '0' order by id desc")
```

Just a note, this is probably not the best solution. But on a low traffic website it should be fine. To make the query a bit more accurate, you'd want to search for the user id based on a unique field like a username or email. This would make sure you get the correct id back.

**EDIT 3**
Here is an example of checking for the user's email. This is just the mysql query, you'll have to adjust this for php. Sorry I'm in class right now.

```
"SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE `banned` = '0' and email='user@email.com' limit 1
```

Comment: No luck with adding mysql_insert_id(). Still user_id 1 :( I added it after - mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());}

Comment: Did you do something like `$userId = mysql_insert_id()`?

Comment: yes tried $id= mysql_insert_id(); and $user_id= mysql_insert_id();

Comment: That's strange. So in your database, does a row get inserted in the user table?

Comment: Additionally, do you get a value back from mysql_insert_id()? If you do get a value back, I will edit my answer, and make it clearer.

Comment: yes when I register a user the row is inserted into the user table with id=2. no value back,nothing, just goes into the language table as normal, but with user id=1  and returns me to 'myaccount.php' page as specified

Comment: Ok, I added an alternate solution to get the latest id inserted.

Comment: Oh no, now when I go back to id=1 its coming up with user_id=2 in the language table!

Comment: do you have solution to search by email as the email has to be unique?

Comment: I added the sql query that you'd use to select a user based on the email. You'll need to convert to php though.

Comment: ok thanks. sorry how would I put it as their email which is in the users table? I've put =$user_email but not sure how to define it

Comment: When you insert the user information in the user table, you are storing their email. That means you have the email already. I don't have your code for that, so I can't tell you exactly, but just use that value in the query.